# How to do regression for this stochastic process?

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, regression, time-series, gaussian

I wonder if there is some good way to determine the parameters for a random process. In my research work, I have a random process of the following form:
$$
X_t=\alpha_{1}G_{t-1}+\alpha_{2}G_{t-2}+...+\alpha_{k}G_{t-k}
$$
Where $\alpha_i$ are unknown parameters, $G_j$ are i.i.d. Gaussian variables. $k$ is known fixed number.

We can sample the random process $X_t$ for a long time and we are trying to obtain the parameter $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ...\alpha_k$ as well as the mean and variance of the random variable $G_j$?

Does anyone know a good way to determine this regression problem? And what area are these problems belong to?

Comment: Do you observe the $G_i$?

Comment: @Dasherman No, only the process is observable

Comment: Do you know $k$? And do you know anything more about the distribution of the $G_i$?

Comment: @Dasherman Yes, we can use different fixed $k$ to do regression.

Comment: And do you know anything more about the distribution of the $G_i$? Are they Gaussian, are they independent or even iid, are they stationary, etc.?

Comment: @beedrill The process you have written down is an $MA(q)$ process, which falls under the general ARMA theory. The parameters in your model can be obtained via MLE methods.

Answer (score 2):

The process you have written down is an $MA(q)$ process, which falls under the general $ARMA$ processes theory. Let me write your model in a more standard way:

$$X_t = \epsilon_t + \theta_1 \epsilon_{t-1} + \ldots + \theta_q\epsilon_{t-q}$$

where $\epsilon_t$ is an iid sequence with $\sigma_\epsilon^2 = \mathbb{E}(\epsilon_t^2) < \infty$ and $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon_t) = 0$. One observes that this process is stationary and the autocorrelation function is given by:
$$\gamma (h) = \mathbb{E}(X_t X_{t+h}) = \frac{-\theta_h + \theta_1 \theta_{h+1} + \theta_2 \theta_{h+2} + \ldots + \theta_{q-h} \theta_q}{1 + \theta_1^2 + \ldots + \theta_q^2}$$
for $h = 1, 2, \ldots, q$. By considering the empirical version of this function, i.e. $\hat{\gamma}$, one obtains $q$ non-linear equations in $q$ unknowns, which can then be placed into a solver. To estimate $\sigma_\epsilon^2$, one may use the variance formula for $X_t \sim MA(q)$: $$\sigma_X^2 = \sigma_\epsilon^2 (1 + \theta_1^2 + \ldots + \theta_q^2)$$

where $\sigma_X^2 = Var(X_t)$.

Alternatively, if one posits that $\epsilon_t \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$, one may write down the likelihood function of $(X_1, \ldots , X_n)$ and find estimates via maximum likelihood estimation. See e.g. [Maximum Likelihood Estimation for MA Processes](https://www.nber.org/system/files/chapters/c12707/c12707.pdf).

For more information about MA and ARMA processes, you may consult the time series texts by Box and Jenkins, Shumway and Stoffer, or Brockwell and Davis, to name just three.